# Will this CUDA code execute in-order and asynchronously?

Tags: cuda

- Will the code below execute in order? 
  (I cannot put the device-to-device copy of `cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray()` in `stream`)
- Will the code below execute asynchronously? 
  (`cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray()` does not have an asynchronous counterpart)

I know the code sample can be implemented more efficiently, however it's merely intended as an example.

```
for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
{
    cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray( dst, src );                   // device to device copy.
    cudaBindTextureToArray( texture_reference, dst, ... )   // bind dst to texture.
    kernel<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream >>>( out )       // compute an array.
    cudaMemcpy2DToArrayAsync( src_p, out, stream )          // copy result to src.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but may be you can use `cudaMemcpy3DAsync` to copy from array to array asynchronously. As the `struct cudaMemcpy3DParms` has fields for source and destination `cudaArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Since all kernel calls and all `cudaMemcpy2DToArrayAsync` calls use the same stream, this will be processed synchronously. One streams can't do multiple things at the same time. However, if you wanted multiple streams to the work, you could do something of the form:

```
NSTREAMS = 8;
cudaStream_t streams [NSTREAMS ];

for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < NSTREAMS; ++ii)
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[ii])) );

for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
{
    cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray( dst, src );                      // device to device copy.
    cudaBindTextureToArray( texture_reference, dst, ... )      // bind dst to texture.
    kernel<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream[i] >>>( out )       // compute an array.
    cudaMemcpy2DToArrayAsync( src_p, out, stream[i] )          // copy result to src.
}


for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < NSTREAMS; ++ii)
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaStreamDestroy(streams[ii]) );
```

However, this way you are still slightly dependent on waiting for `cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray` every step, as this function shows synchronous behaviour.

Comment: I read in the cuda programming API that device to device copies from functions without the suffix 'Async' are still asynchronous. So will the host block each time until `cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray()` is finished?

Comment: The API reference for `cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray()` says that it "exhibits synchronous behaviour for most use cases." This may or may not be a case in which it'll be 'more' asynchronous, but I wouldn't count on it.